# Capistrano rbenv deploy gets stuck and doesn't print anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rbenv

#### Steps to reproduce

`cap production deploy`
and that's it, just gets stuck forever until I abort it

#### Expected behavior

- Continue with deploying
- It must to print a TimeOut error log or something else

#### Actual behavior

When I run: `cap production deploy` it shows nothing, just keeps waiting
But when I run: `cap production deploy --trace` it shows this:

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rbenv:validate (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:validate
```

#### System configuration

https://gist.github.com/anyelopetit/7320fc8141554ea4b75ec88bb02f8132

Comment: Did you find a solution? Suffering that right now